# Display always full screen in excel with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want that my excel xml always display in full screen view.

For this I code the next:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
          Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
          ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
          Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
    End Sub
```

It is working fine until I minimize excel, once I maximize again It shows in normal view mode, how to proceed? Any suggestion? The main idea is to remove the tool bars as I don't want user to interact with them.

Comment: Regarding your point that worksheet restores when interaction takes place with Minimize , Maximize options. I would strictly advise you not to temper with system settings, However latest edit includes related code which interacts with windows API level.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this into the workbook module. It will maximize the windows whenever it gets resized:

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window)
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an event that you can trap I'd try adding this to your ThisWorkbook module

```
Option Explicit

Private mbToggle As Boolean
Private mlPriorState(-1 To 0) As XlWindowState


Private Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window)

    mlPriorState(mbToggle) = Wn.WindowState
    mbToggle = Not mbToggle

    If Wn.WindowState = xlNormal And mlPriorState(mbToggle) <> xlMaximized Then
        ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
    End If

End Sub
```

Though this may only work on windows that represent the worksheet/workbook.  I'd try this first; other solutions involving Windows API  are way more complicated.

Folded in some feedback.  This code works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your encouraging words.

Comment: How would you prevent the window from being remaximized when the user wants to minimize it? When I just tried it `Application.Windowstate` returned `xlNormal` when I minimized the window.

Answer (score 0):

Workbook_Activate will bring full screen mode while other will bring back normal mode.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    On Error Resume Next
    With Application
        .DisplayFullScreen = True
        .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = False
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    On Error Resume Next
    With Application
        .DisplayFullScreen = False
        .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = True
    End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT**
you shouldn't 'modify' the way Windows works at a system level. However, if you really, really must; add the following to a new module and call the SetStyle procedure.

**That code is offered *UNTESTED*'as is' - the API is a way to modify Windows at a system level and can be dangerous (sudden crashes, data file corruption...) if you do not know what you are doing.**

VB:

```
Option Explicit 

 'Related Windows API functions
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long 
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long 
Private Declare Function GetSystemMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal bRevert As Long) As Long 
Private Declare Function DeleteMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hMenu As Long, ByVal nPosition As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long 
Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long 
Private Declare Function SetFocus Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long 
Private Declare Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndLock As Long) As Long 

 'Window style constants
Private Const GWL_STYLE As Long = (-16) '// The offset of a window's style
Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE As Long = (-20) '// The offset of a window's extended style
Private Const WS_CAPTION As Long = &HC00000 '// Title bar bit
Private Const WS_SYSMENU As Long = &H80000 '// System menu bit
Private Const WS_THICKFRAME As Long = &H40000 '// Sizable frame bit
Private Const WS_MINIMIZEBOX As Long = &H20000 '// Minimize box bit
Private Const WS_MAXIMIZEBOX As Long = &H10000 '// Maximize box bit
Private Const WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW As Long = &H80 '// Tool Window: small titlebar bit

 'Constant to identify the Close menu item
Private Const SC_CLOSE As Long = &HF060 


Public Sub SetStyle() 

    Dim lStyle As Long, hMenu As Long 

     'Get the basic window style
    lStyle = GetWindowLong(Application.hWnd, GWL_STYLE) 

    If lStyle = 0 Then 
        MsgBox "Unable to determine application window handle...", vbExclamation, "Error" 
        Exit Sub 
    End If 

     '// Build up the basic window style flags for the form
     '// Uncomment the features you want...
     '// Set it True to enable, FALSE to disable
     '// The first 2 are obvious, ThickFrame controls if the Window is sizable or not.

     '// SetBit lStyle, WS_CAPTION, True
     '// SetBit lStyle, WS_SYSMENU, False
     '// SetBit lStyle, WS_THICKFRAME, False
    SetBit lStyle, WS_MINIMIZEBOX, False 
    SetBit lStyle, WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, False 

     'Set the basic window styles
    SetWindowLong Application.hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle 

     'Get the extended window style
    lStyle = GetWindowLong(Application.hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) 


     '// Handle the close button differently
     '// If Close button is wanted
     '// hMenu = GetSystemMenu(Application.hWnd, 1)

     '// Not wanted - delete it from the control menu
    hMenu = GetSystemMenu(Application.hWnd, 0) 
    DeleteMenu hMenu, SC_CLOSE, 0& 


     'Update the window with the changes
    DrawMenuBar Application.hWnd 
    SetFocus Application.hWnd 

End Sub 


 '// Set or clear a bit from a style flag
Private Sub SetBit(ByRef lStyle As Long, ByVal lBit As Long, ByVal bOn As Boolean) 

    If bOn Then 
        lStyle = lStyle Or lBit 
    Else 
        lStyle = lStyle And Not lBit 
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: Good one @skkakkar

Comment: The code works fine, but it works only with the workbook changes (minimize/maximize) it is not working with Excel application minimize/maximize. As the main porpoise is that the user does not have access to the toolbar Home/Insert/PageLayout/Formulas/Datas..... any other option to hide it?

Comment: @Make Standard I do have access to such routines, but experts advise very strongly not to use any routine which tempers minimize or maximize button as you can permanently lose these buttons.